# Is it possible to create a staggered layout where children of known aspect ratios are given their maximum size?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to lay out widgets as in the attached image, just using Rows and Columns? The purple boxes are known to be 3:4 (they are `AspectRatio` widgets) but their size should be maximized.

At first, I thought this would be a basic Row with two children. The first child, an `AspectRatio` with the visual widget inside it. The second child, a column with two children: the other two `AspectRatio`s.

But Flutter always explodes with all sorts of errors about being unable to calculate the size. Based on [this documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints), I think I understand why. I'm leaning towards "this is impossible", but maybe I'm missing something. I've tried various combinations of `Expanded`, `mainAxisSize.min`, etc.

I could always just use a LayoutBuilder to get the screen width and lay the elements out with SizedBoxes, but it would be nice to leave the layout up to Flutter.

[image: Illustration of the scenario]

Comment: imho, good time to learn `CustomMultiChildLayout` ;-) - `Scaffold`, `NavigationToolbar` and couple of other complex layouts use it internally - maybe it would be possible to do that using existing blocks but ...

Comment: Thanks, I'll spend some time looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping your AspectRatio with Expanded you can achieve the layout. Here is the code for the same.

```
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 3 / 4,
          child: Container(color: Colors.red),
        ),
      ),
      Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 3 / 4,
              child: Container(color: Colors.green),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 3 / 4,
              child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

You can check the same on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/115c1e1c6db3b3fca1d85253365a4d9d).

Comment: I don't think that quite solves it. As the available space resizes, the red container gets smaller. In the layout I'm trying to achieve, it should fill the entire available horizontal space in such a way that the aspect ratios of all the containers are maintained.